# Calling datepicker options function from inside another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datepicker, promise

I have the following function that is using a promise to return data from asynchronous ajax call:

```
$("#mySelect").on('change', function() {
      var mySelectValue = $('#mySelect').val();
      var promise = getAvailableDates(mySelectValue);

      promise.done( function(data) { // tested and returning data

        var array = data;

        $('#a_date').datepicker({ // this function not working
           dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
           beforeShowDay: function (date) {      
               var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
               return [array.indexOf(string) >= 0 ]
           }
        });

      });
   });
```

Why the `$('#a_date').datepicker()` function doesn't work inside another function?

It doesn't respond to my `dateFormat` and `beforeShowDay` settings based on data returned from my Ajax call.

How can I adjust Datepicker settings from inside a returned promise?

Comment: have you included the libs?

Comment: @Valkyriee Do you mean CSS and JS? Yes, the datepicker is working itself, but the options function is not working from within the returned promise. Outside of it, it's working well.

Comment: Can you please post the value of `array` variable . Rest of code seems correct. A simple example of same assignment is [here](http://codepen.io/farooqkhan/pen/RVwrqe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `destroy` the first `datetimepicker` object created before reinitialize it, by the following statement:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("destroy");
```

see follow:

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
    
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
      $("#datepicker").datepicker("destroy");
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
      });
      console.log("Format changed, try to select a new date");
    });
  } );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Change format">
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm! Being a JavaScript noob, it's these little things that I don't know yet.